# Swift: function with default parameter before non-default parameter

Tags: swift

say I have a function that has non-default parameter after default parameter like this:

```
func f(first:Int = 100, second:Int){}
```

how can I call it and use the default value for the first parameter?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The current compiler does allow default parameters in the middle of a parameter list.

[image: screenshot of Playground]

You can call the function like this if you want to use the default value for the `first` parameter:

```
f(1)
```

If you want to supply a new value for the `first` parameter, use its external name:

```
f(first: 3, 1)
```

The documentation [explains](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_220) that parameters with a default value are automatically given an external name:

> Swift provides an automatic external name for any defaulted parameter you define, if you do not provide an external name yourself. The automatic external name is the same as the local name, as if you had written a hash symbol before the local name in your code.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct and you can do it this way in Swift, it is very confusing and should be avoided. Refactoring a function to have default parameters at the end isn’t that much work. Even in this simple case it isn’t completely clear what the call to `f(1)` means. [@Connor’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24102938/133166) should be the accepted one.

Comment: @Rafael I didn't say this was the best practice; I answered the question correctly. Therefore, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18):

You should have the default parameters at the end of the parameter list.

```
func f(second:Int, first:Int = 100){}
f(10)
```

> Place parameters with default values at the end of a function’s
>   parameter list. This ensures that all calls to the function use the
>   same order for their non-default arguments, and makes it clear that
>   the same function is being called in each case.

[Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_204)

Comment: so Using parameter with a default value before those without is meaningless? Why isn't it a compile time error?

Comment: No it's not meaningless, it just not "ensures that all calls to the function use the same order for their non-default arguments". It will work, but could be confusing. So Apple defined a guideline to developers about where to put parameters with default values.

Answer (score 5):

On Swift 3:

```
func defaultParameterBefore(_ x: Int = 1, y: Int ) {}
```

Calling

```
defaultParameterBefore(2)
```

will raise this error

```
error: missing argument for parameter 'y' in call
```

The only exception is:

- There is a parameter before the default parameter;
- **and** the parameter after the default parameter is a closure;
- **and** the closure parameter is the last parametr;
- **and** calling via trailing closure

For example:

```
func defaultParameterBetween(_ x: Int, _ y: Bool = true, _ z: String) {
    if y {
       print(x)
    } else
       z()
    }
}

// error: missing argument for parameter #3 in call
// defaultParameterWithTrailingClosure(1, { print(0) }

// Trailing closure does work, though.
func defaultParameterWithTrailingClosure(_ x: Int, y: Bool = true,
                                     _ z: () -> Void) {
    if y {
        print(x)
    } else {
        z()
    }
}

defaultParameterWithTrailingClosure(1) { print(0) }
```

*swift version*: `DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-04-12`

Comment: Your code example does not work. Should z be an closure `() -> String`, instead of a `String`?

Comment: @iGodric Sorry I forgot the definition of `defaultParameterWithTrailingClosure`. Fixed now.

Comment: So are you saying you can longer do anything similar to the accepted answer unless it's a trailing closure?

Comment: @Honey Yes. Swift 3 is stricter on this.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a method on a class, you need to call it like this

```
class Test
{
    func f(first:Int = 100, second:Int)
    {
        println("first is \(first)")
        println("second is \(second)")
    }

    func other()
    {
        f(second: 4)
        f(first: 30, second: 5)
        //f(4) will not compile, and neither will f(9,12)
    }
}
```

If the function f is global, you need to call it like this:

```
f(4)
f(first: 30, 5)
```

This prints:

```
first is 100
second is 4
first is 30
second is 5
```

Comment: Technically you don't need a label on the required parameter.

Comment: Yes you do. I tried it without the label and it won't compile.

Comment: See the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: I see it. Still doesn't compile on my box. You're using "run as I type". Maybe that's why.

Comment: I get "Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to '(first: Int, second: Int)'".

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? `/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift --version` It compiles for me on swift-600.0.34.4.5

Comment: Swift version 1.0 (swift-600.0.34.4.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0

Comment: `f(4)` works for me in the REPL and in a Playground (after pasting in your code sample). Are you sure you didn't type something wrong?

Comment: I'm human, but I'm pretty damn sure. I believe you though. What version do you have? And this "playground" that people speak of... Is that a REPL in XCode or is it actual code in a project in Xcode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55267/discussion-between-undefined-and-millie-smith).

Comment: `f(second: 4)` shouldn't work as you didn't specify externalParamName. I bet you are using it as a method of a class and not indicating it here.