# Optional parameter in class initialization

Tags: class, swift, initialization, sprite-kit, init

I'm working with Swift, Sprite-Kit and Xcode 6,

I have a class declared like this :

```
class Obstacles: SKSpriteNode
{
    init(initTime: Int, speed: CGFloat, positionX: CGFloat, rotationSpeed: CGFloat)
    {
        self.initTime = initTime
        self.rotationSpeed = rotationSpeed
        self.positionX = positionX

        super.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Rectangle"), color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
        self.speed = speed
    }

    var initTime: Int
    var positionX: CGFloat
    var rotationSpeed: CGFloat = 0
}
```

So I can assign a variable to this class like this :

```
var myVariable = Obstacles(initTime: 100, speed: 3.0, positionX: 10.0, rotationSpeed: 0.0)
```

but if for example I don't want to initialize the rotationSpeed value and have it default to 0.0, how can I manage to do so ? I can't remove the parameter, it results me an error...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you want is to set a default value for rotationSpeed but you are forgetting to declare the type and assign a default value. Instead of saying `rotationSpeed: 0.0)` you would have `rotationSpeed: CGFloat = 0`. Making your initializer look like this:

```
init(initTime: Int, speed: CGFloat, positionX: CGFloat, rotationSpeed: CGFloat = 0)
```

You also might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102925/swift-using-function-parameter-with-default-value-before-non-default-parameter) SO post useful as well

Comment: I already saw this post but after reading it again I understood thanks, my bad

Comment: But how to set a optional argument for the intialization. This answered the intent of the question but not what anyone else is looking for with that questions title.